# Move "sideways" through browser pages without adding to browser history

Tags: javascript, browser-history, html5-history

- At a book page, the user clicks **Chapter 1** in the table of contents.
- At the Chapter 1 page, the user clicks **Next Chapter** to go to Chapter 2.
- The user may click **Next Chapter** any number of times to move through chapters.
- At any chapter page, if the user clicks the **Back** button, the user should go back to the book page, not back to a previously viewed chapter page. In other words, movement through chapter pages is kind of "sideways" without adding to the browser history stack.

QUESTION:

What Javascript must be executed when **Next Chapter** is clicked to effectively remove the current chapter page from the browser history and then go to the new chapter page as so that the history stack looks as if the user had come to the new chapter page from the book page?

EFFORTS:

- I've read a number of posts and have read the documentation, especially the Mozilla doc on manipulating the browser history.
- I've tried calling history.back() (to pop the current entry) followed by proceeding to the next chapter, but the current chapter just stays in the history, so that I come back to it when I click the Back button.
- I've tried history.replaceState(), but that doesn't seem to help.
- It seems like what I need is something like history.popState() followed by proceeding to the next chapter.
- I'm sure I'm just missing some simple, key ingredient.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, I would call replaceState every time a new chapter is loaded, that way if you go back you'll get to the Book page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, with thanks for inspiration from Limbo. The onclick event from a next or previous link calls this function:

```
function sidewaysLink()
{
    history.replaceState({}, "", this.getAttribute("href"));
    history.go(0);
    return false;
}
```

Not sure why it took me so much blundering to figure this out. The operation is simple: `history.replaceState()` replaces the entry at the top of the browser stack and `history.go(0)` goes to that top entry. The `return false` keeps the browser from acting on the link upon return.

I don't know what the first parameter of history.replaceState() should be. It's identified as a "state object" (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API, which gives an example). I'm passing an empty object and it seems to work. The second parameter is identified as the "title", which the documentation says can safely be an empty string.

Grateful to hear from anyone who sees a flaw in this approach or who can suggest improvement. Seems to work well.

Comment: you should not really use return false on its own, before your return false  your `sidewaysLink` should take the event argument `sidewaysLink(evt)` then you should call `evt.preventDefault();` return false also stops the propagation of events whereas with the `preventDefault()` it does not. To read more about this check out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-to-use-preventdefault-vs-return-false-in-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [`history`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) package.

Your code will look like

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"
const history = createBrowserHistory()
```

Then for **Next Chapter** you will use `history.replace("/url/to/your/next/chapter")`.
If user goes to first chapter from book page, then every next chapter will replace current location, that means that previous location will reffer to **Book**.
It means that for **Back** you will use `history.goBack()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It did help! See below.

Answer (score 1):

So as I understand it your unable to use the history object because if they jump chapter and press back page they will go back to where they were before clicking back page and not back a page.

So a way you can fix this is to have the chapter pages saved in an array
E.G

```
let currentPage = 0;
let currentChapter = 0;
let totalPages = 97;
let chapters = [0,3,25,51,63]

let nextPage = () => {
    if(currentPage+1 > totalPages) return;
    currentPage++;
    if(currentPage > chapters[currentChapter]){
        currentChapter++;
    }
}
let prevPage = () => {
    if(currentPage == 0) return;
    currentPage--;
    if(currentPage < chapters[currentChapter]){
        currentChapter--;
    }
}
let nextChapter = () => {
    if(currentChapter+1 > chapters.length) return;
    currentChapter++;
    currentPage = chapters[currentChapter]
}
let previusChapter = () => {
    if(currentChapter == 0) return;
    currentChapter--;
    currentPage = chapters[currentChapter]
}
```

With this, you can use pushState to change the URL based on `currentPage` in sll of the methods, then you can work out `currentChapter` from the `currentPage` on page load this will allow for a refresh to happen.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, @Martin Baker. I have a simpler solution that works. Seems my description of the problem wasn't as clear as it could have been.